# Why can I eject Skype?

Tags: macos

I am new to Mac and simply don't understand the concept of ejecting installed programs - its not very intuitive at all.

Why is skype appearing as a device in Finder and why can I eject Skype?

Comment: i think what you are doing is mounting a downloaded 'install disk', which can be ejected. the program should be dragged to your application folder from the install disk and the install disk be ejected afterwards.

Comment: Man, hide your address. "its not very intuitive at all." For this, MAC fans will hunt ya' down. :P

Comment: It's just a bazaar concept.  Why mount a disc in the first instance.

Comment: Never installed an OS?

Comment: @Shiki Those networking guys are vicious. Don't ever double a MAC on a network.

Comment: @Shiki: Mac fans will hunt you down for putting Mac in all caps too ;)

Comment: @Mr. Man - True. :( So far I've been able to repel them..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that you mean you've been ejecting the disk image that Skype.app came in. Installing most program in Mac OS X is as simple as mounting the disk image and then dragging the app to the Applications folder (not obligatory, but preferred), then ejecting the mounted disk image.